# Insert weekday to the diary date format

Tags: emacs

The format of diary is

> Mar 18, 2019
>   This is my diary

I want to append  day of the week to it.

[image]

the color of Monday does not fit to the date,

Upon checking the documentation,  there is no such a weekday format

```
The file’s entries are lines beginning with any of the forms
specified by the variable ‘diary-date-forms’, which by default
uses the forms of ‘diary-american-date-forms’:

            MONTH/DAY
            MONTH/DAY/YEAR
            MONTHNAME DAY
            MONTHNAME DAY, YEAR
            DAYNAME
```

Is it possible to get the weekday inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your Emacs [config file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

```
(require 'calendar)
(setq diary-date-forms
      (cons '(backup monthname " *" day ", *" year ", *" dayname "\\W")
        diary-american-date-forms))
```

What this does is to make sure calendar is loaded so that diary-american-date-forms is available, and then tack on an extra date form to it. The 'backup' is necessary because the first part of the new format is the same as one of the existing ones.